# Django: how to save model into different database tables depending on which ManyToOne relationship it belongs to?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django. My app have two models, Customer and Order, where each customer can have multiple orders. So what I did is to set up a ForeignKey(Cusotmer) relationship in Order model:

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer,null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    ordername = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

In this case, if I want to query the orders by a specific customer `customer1`, I can use `Order.objects.filter(Customer=customer1)`. But I wonder if it is possible to save the order data for each customer in a separate database table? Right now all the orders are saved in the same table and misuse of filters can let customers view other customers' orders.

Comment: Can you provide a case where this is useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I wonder if it is possible to save the order data for each customer in a separate database table?

Even if this were possible, you definitely *do not* want to store each customer's orders in a separate database table. Relational databases are designed for data with the same structure to be stored as rows in a table, and that's how Django models (which define the structure of your data) expect to interact with your database.

The correct approach is to save all customers' orders in a single table, using your `Order` model, and use the Django ORM to filter based on the user.

> Right now all the orders are saved in the same table and misuse of filters can let customers view other customers' orders.

Even if you used separate tables for each customer's orders, you would still need to determine which table's data to display to the user (just like how with all the orders in a single table, you have to determine which rows to use). If you use the Django ORM correctly (to filter the data based on the user who makes the request), this is a non-issue.

Comment: The statement that it is not possible is incorrect as I have seen some packages that allow you to make tables dynamically (I consider this a bad idea though), but I completely agree with you on the rest of your answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the statement that it's not possible and instead emphasize that it's not a good idea.